# SettingUINavigationbar textAlignment with UIappearance possible?

Tags: text-alignment, uiappearance

I just wondered if it is possible to globally change the `UINavigationBar's` title `textAlignment` like you can do with its font:

```
NSMutableDictionary *titleBarAttributes     = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary: [[UINavigationBar appearance] titleTextAttributes]];
[titleBarAttributes setValue:[UIFont fontWithName:myFontName] forKey:NSFontAttributeName];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:titleBarAttributes];
```

Does something like `[titleBarAttributes setValue:NSTextAlignmentLeft forKey:NSTextAlignment]`
exist for UIAppereance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am afraid the answer is no. You can only have the following keys for the text attributes from the [NSString UIKit Additions Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006893):

```
NSString *const UITextAttributeFont; 
NSString *const UITextAttributeTextColor; 
NSString *const UITextAttributeTextShadowColor; 
NSString *const UITextAttributeTextShadowOffset;
```

But you can still set the titleView property of the UINavigationItem with UILabel and you can set the text alignment there.

You can create a base subclass of view controller, set the navigation item titleView property, and create subsequent view controllers by subclassing that base view controller.

Comment: It looks like you are right and `UIAppearance` can not handle this behaviour. Unfortunately I already had implemented a superclass with a `UILabel` as a subview, I just wondered if there are other possibilities.